# Need to copy file from local to server using File.Copy(),

Tags: file, transfer, file-copying

Need to copy file from local to server using File.Copy(), i am repeatedly getting the error given path not in correct format

didnt expect a format error, the format im giving is this File.Copy(@"Drive\Folder\File",@"\Server\Drive\Folder\File")

Comment: What language are you using? We need a bit more to go on :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.